# my .htacces is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, .htaccess

I would edit the .htaccess file, but there only was :

`Order deny,allow
Deny from all`

that is normal?
This file was in the subdirectory app , in the root directory there wasn't any file

Comment: you can always get any files missing from here:http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, without the .htaccess in the root directory your magento project won't force (non-existent) page look ups to go via the index.php and the magento core. Try copying one from a fresh install.  You can download the files from https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ - be sure to match the correct version with your install.  You might just have an .htaccess.sample file to rename to .htaccess.

If your site is working fine, then perhaps you just don't have permission to see the file.

The .htaccess inside app folder is correct.

Comment: I upload a new htaccess file, now my site it's okey , thank you so much!